# Chart.js - How to display title in multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chart.js, how to display title in multiple lines like shown below ? I try using `title: 'Chart.js\nLine Chart'` and `'Chart.js<br>Line Chart'` but they didn't work.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or something like that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try giving title as string[] array as shown in below example.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: ['Chart.js','Line Chart']
            }
        }
    })
```

Please go through the reference for more details. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19264730)

Comment: @Mark Meyer Thanks for the review comment